# Using getResources and a custom date TV, how can I limit my results by the year entered in my TV?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

In MODx Revolution, while using getResources and a custom date TV (called: press-release-date), how can I limit my results by year (using a URL param to set the year, so I could enter any year)?

For example, my URL has page.html?year=2012

I want my results from getResources to only include ones associated with that year. I believe I want to use the &where property (if so, I am certainly botching the formatting):

```
&where=`{"press-release-date":[[*press-release-date:strtotime:date=`%Y`]:isequalto:`2012`]}`
```

I've also tried

```
&where=`{[[*press-release-date]]:[[*press-release-date:strtotime:date=`%Y`]:isequalto:`2012`]}`
```

Thanks!

UPDATE:
This is the full code I am using currently:

```
[[!getResources?
    &parents=`780,781,782,783,784`
    &tpl=`list-press-tpl`
    &limit=`1000`
    &sortdir=`DESC`
    &includeTVs=`1`
    &includeContent=`1` 
    &depth=`0`
    &showHidden=`1`
    &sortbyTV=`press-release-date`
    &where=`{[[*press-release-date]]:[[*press-release-date:strtotime:date=`%Y`]:isequalto:`2012`]}`
]]
```

Comment: I ended up going a different route for the sake of time, but I am leaving this question open in case someone else has some more feedback in the future. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to use the &tvFilters attribute: http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/getResources you will probably have to also &includeTVs, &includeTvsList and ~possibly~ also &processTVList. As to how to strip the post value from the url, you may have to write a quick little snippet that grabs all your url variables & sets them as placeholders. something along the lines of:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){

$modx->setPlaceholder($key,$value);

}
```

Then you should be able to access them:

```
&where=`{[[*press-release-date]]:[[*press-release-date:strtotime:date=`%Y`]:isequalto:`[[+year]]`]}`
```

at a guess... not tested.:)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `tvFilters` instead. But you will have to translate your `[[+year]]` into your `press-release-date` date format and limit search inside intertleave:

```
&tvFilters=`press-release-date>=[[+year:dec:strtotime]]||press-release-date<=[[+year:strtotime]]`
```

- http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Input+and+Output+Filters+%28Output+Modifiers%29
- http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Date+Formats
- https://www.php.net/strtotime